# Subtracting Dates in Oralce

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a table with the following code. However I am having issues subtracting the dates as one of the columns (yes I have tried researching this issue on the site but I'm still having issues).

Whenever I run this code I receive the following error: "AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required." "AM" is already included, so I'm not sure where I am going wrong.  Any ideas?

```
   CREATE TABLE FINAL
AS
    select 
        policy_id, 
        ECY, 
        TO_DATE(end_dt,'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS AM') - TO_DATE(start_dt,'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS AM') maxdays, 
        start_dt, 
        end_dt,
        cancellation_date,
        County
    from counttable
    where (Cancellation_Date is null or Cancellation_Date > &enddate)
    and ECY > 0;
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What data type are the `start_dt` and `end_dt` columns? What is your `enddate` variable defined as? And what is your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT? (And why are you creating a table as a snapshot of data at this point in time; do you really want a view?

Comment: AM is not a format but a string. There is a special keyword to handle AM and PM.

Comment: can you show some data?

Comment: Also what data type is `cancellation_date`, and does `&enddate` contain quotes?

Answer (score 0):

If your start_dt and end_dt  truly are VARCHAR columns then I'm willing to bet you've mangled up your date format string with reference to one or more rows

Run these two queries and see what I mean:

```
--works ok
select to_date('01-jan-1901 12:34 pm', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi am') from dual

--complains "am/pm required"
select to_date('01-jan-1901 12:34:56 pm', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi am') from dual
```

In short, it is NOT complaining that "your date format string lacks an AM/PM field", it is complaining "while trying to parse the table data to the format you gave, I encountered something other than "AM" or "PM" in the data when your date format string promised me I would find AM/A.M./PM/P.M."

In my test queries above, for example, the data in the "table" contains `:56` seconds on the end of the time, but my date format string promised oracle that it would find AM/PM in the data as soon as it had finished parsing the minutes. Essentially, my date format string lied.

Be sure your date format string accurately describes the way your string represents the date in every single one of your table rows. Even one row in a million with some corrupt data that violates the format, will halt the query. This is why it's good to store dates as datetime type, not varchar

If your columns are not VARCHAR, then some implicit conversion to varchar is going on before TO_DATE() can start its work. If your columns are dates already, to not TO_DATE them. If they're something other than VARCHAR (like if theyre an INT of the number of minutes after midnight Jan 1 1970) treat them accordingly --> convert them to dates by whatever way their representation requires